# Visual Studio Code Intellisense Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

What are valid values for the c_cpp_properties.json tag "intelliSenseMode" ?

It defaults to clang-x64, but I am compiling with g++ so is there another value I can use there? I can not find any documentation about it.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md - specifies 2 possibilities "msvc-x64" / "clang-x64". Second is default for Linux env

Comment: Huh I don't know what I googled wrong but that page did not appear in my first 10 results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Artemy Vysotsky did not post his answer as an answer:

The documentation states that `"msvc-x64"` and `"clang-x64"` are the only possible values.

Comment: As of now it is also possible to choose `gcc-x64`. (supposedly the default value on Linux but my Linux vscode installation defaults to `clang-x64`)

Answer (score 7):

When editing the .json configuration file, just type `"intelliSenseMode": ""` and let intelliSense itself help.

Actually you may use the option `"intelliSenseMode": "${default}"` to allow self selection.

As of today, the defaults are: clang-x64 for Mac; msvc-x64 for Windows; and gcc-x64 for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting this warning because of line number 16 [image]

Just change `"intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"` to `"intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, if you're using Windows

I used "g++.exe"
[image]

Then I changed the "IntelliSense mode" to "windows-gcc-x64" to get rid of the warning
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since v0.25, 32 bit modes are supported. The valid options are `msvc-x64`, `gcc-x64`, `clang-x64` and their 32 bit counterparts `msvc-x86`, `gcc-x86`, `clang-x86`. There's also the `${default}` option that Fábio Lobão mentions.

(Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2312)

Answer (score 0):

Hovering on the `intelliSenseMode` in the file `c_cpp_properties.json` shows this documentation popup.

[image: screenshot of popup on intelliSenseMode]

It pretty much says that valid values have to be specified in the format `<platform>-<compiler>-<architecture>`. The older `<compiler>-<architecture>` variants  are legacy modes and are converted automatically to the newer format based on the platform. So, some valid values can be

1. `linux-gcc-x64`
2. `windows-msvc-x64`
3. `macos-clang-x64`

But when I checked in the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) it says the following.

[image: screenshot of documentation]

**Conclusion**

I would go with the contextual documentation since official documentation builds can lag behind.

---

**Version Details**

- Version: 1.73.0
- Electron: 19.0.17
- Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
- Node.js: 16.14.2
- V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
- OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-52-generic snap
- Sandboxed: No
- C/C++ Extension: v1.12.4